# Why Doesn't Variable Work When I Assign It In Array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I need to use a variable in the below code but it doesn't work, I don't understand why.

Working code;

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post__in' => array(
        16405,16362,16290,16434,16661
    ),
) );
```

Code that doesn't work;

```
$featured_content_id = get_theme_mod( 'laura_featured_content_id' );
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
'post__in' => array(
$featured_content_id
),
) );
```

When I look at $featured_content_id variable using echo and var_dump(), it seems to be correct. Which means the result is 16405, 16362, 16290, 16434, 16661 but it doesn't work inside a array. Also it doesn't work if I directly use $featured_content_id = '16405, 16362, 16290, 16434, 16661'. Do I have to write it inside array?

Comment: Can you show what the var_dump of `$featured_content_id` looks like? If it's already an array, you don't need to surround it inside an array.

Comment: And if its a string it wont result in an array of multiple numbers but ana rray with one occurance of `'16405,16362,16290,16434,16661'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Assuming `$featured_content_id` is a string:***

You probably want `explode(',', $featured_content_id)` and not `array($featured_content_id)`. And in case it has to be a number and not a string, you'd also need `array_map('intval', ...)` around it.

This is because what you currently do will give you an array like `array('16405,16362,16290,16434,16661')` which is an array with **one** element that is a string. What you actually want is to split the string (using `,` as separator) into an array with one element for each part.

```php
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post__in' => array_map('intval', explode(',', $featured_content_id)),
) );
```

---

***Assuming `$featured_content_id` is an array:***

If it's already an array, all you need is to pass the variable directly, without wrapping it in `array( )`.

```php
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post__in' => $featured_content_id,
) );
```

Comment: Thanks. Solved with first method as it is string.